# How to connect Winlogbeat to Elasticsearch dockrized Cluster using SSL?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, elastic-stack, elk

For the past week I am trying to connect a Winlogbeat(Which is on my host machine) To an elasticsearch Cluster that I set up on an Ubuntu VM using dockers.

Following [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html#get-started-docker) tutorial. (In the tutorial they don't explain how to connect a Beat)

My problem is with the SSL configuration (Of the Winlogbeat) I just can't get it right for some reason.

This is the error I get on the windows machine after running the setup command (**.\winlogbeat.exe setup -e**) -

```
2021-02-22T01:42:13.286+0200    ERROR   instance/beat.go:971    Exiting: couldn't connect to any of 
the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [error connecting to Elasticsearch at 
https://192.168.216.129:9200: Get "https://192.168.216.129:9200": x509: certificate signed by unknown 
authority]
Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [error connecting to 
Elasticsearch at https://192.168.216.129:9200: Get "https://192.168.216.129:9200": x509: certificate 
signed by unknown authority]
```

And on the Elasticsearch node I get this error -

```
es01     | "at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty- 
common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]",
es01     | "at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]",
es01     | "Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate",
```

I tried different methods without any success -

1. Using openssl to generate self-signed certificate for Winlogbeat (Using this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309%22)).
   After that I tried to add the new CA I generated to the es_certs volume and I tried to modify the
   elastic-docker-tls.yml so it will except the new CA (I failed at that).
2. I changed the instances.yml file by adding a winlogbeat section -

- name: winlogbeat
dns:
- <My Computer Name>
ip:
- 192.168.1.136

```
and ran  docker-compose -f create-certs.yml run --rm create_certs on a fresh install of the stack which 
resulted in the creation of a winlogbeat.crt and winlogbeat.key  but still it didn't work.
```

3. I also tried to play with the verfication_mode changing it to "none" but it didn't work either.

I don't know what else to try and I failed to find a good source that details the ssl configuration to beats to elk on a docker environment.

**This is the elastic-docker-tls.yml file:**

```html
version: '2.2'

services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial 
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true 
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate 
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es01/es01.key
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

    healthcheck:
      test: curl --cacert $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt -s https://localhost:9200 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es02/es02.key
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic

  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${VERSION}
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=trial
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=$CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=$CERTS_DIR/es03/es03.key
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic
  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${VERSION}
    container_name: kib01
    depends_on: {"es01": {"condition": "service_healthy"}}
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      SERVERNAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: kibana_system
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: CHANGEME
      ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES: $CERTS_DIR/ca/ca.crt
      SERVER_SSL_ENABLED: "true"
      SERVER_SSL_KEY: $CERTS_DIR/kib01/kib01.key
      SERVER_SSL_CERTIFICATE: $CERTS_DIR/kib01/kib01.crt
    volumes:
      - certs:$CERTS_DIR
    networks:
      - elastic
volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local
  certs:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

**This is the Winlogbeat configuration**

```html
###################### Winlogbeat Configuration Example ########################


winlogbeat.event_logs:
  - name: Application
    ignore_older: 72h

  - name: System

  - name: Security
    processors:
      - script:
          lang: javascript
          id: security
          file: ${path.home}/module/security/config/winlogbeat-security.js

  - name: Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational
    processors:
      - script:
          lang: javascript
          id: sysmon
          file: ${path.home}/module/sysmon/config/winlogbeat-sysmon.js

  - name: Windows PowerShell
    event_id: 400, 403, 600, 800
    processors:
      - script:
          lang: javascript
          id: powershell
          file: ${path.home}/module/powershell/config/winlogbeat-powershell.js

  - name: Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational
    event_id: 4103, 4104, 4105, 4106
    processors:
      - script:
          lang: javascript
          id: powershell
          file: ${path.home}/module/powershell/config/winlogbeat-powershell.js

  - name: ForwardedEvents
    tags: [forwarded]
    processors:
      - script:
          when.equals.winlog.channel: Security
          lang: javascript
          id: security
          file: ${path.home}/module/security/config/winlogbeat-security.js
      - script:
          when.equals.winlog.channel: Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational
          lang: javascript
          id: sysmon
          file: ${path.home}/module/sysmon/config/winlogbeat-sysmon.js
      - script:
          when.equals.winlog.channel: Windows PowerShell
          lang: javascript
          id: powershell
          file: ${path.home}/module/powershell/config/winlogbeat-powershell.js
      - script:
          when.equals.winlog.channel: Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational
          lang: javascript
          id: powershell
          file: ${path.home}/module/powershell/config/winlogbeat-powershell.js

# ====================== Elasticsearch template settings =======================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false


# ================================== General ===================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
#name:

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
#tags: ["service-X", "web-tier"]

# Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the
# output.
#fields:
#  env: staging

# ================================= Dashboards =================================
# These settings control loading the sample dashboards to the Kibana index. Loading
# the dashboards is disabled by default and can be enabled either by setting the
# options here or by using the `setup` command.
#setup.dashboards.enabled: false

# The URL from where to download the dashboards archive. By default this URL
# has a value which is computed based on the Beat name and version. For released
# versions, this URL points to the dashboard archive on the artifacts.elastic.co
# website.
#setup.dashboards.url:

# =================================== Kibana ===================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:

  # Kibana Host
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
  host: "https://192.168.216.129:5601"
   
  setup.kibana.ssl.enabled: true
  setup.kibana.ssl.certificate_authorities: ["C:\\Program Files\\Winlogbeat\\ca.crt"]
  setup.kibana.ssl.certificate: "C:\\Program Files\\Winlogbeat\\winlogbeat.crt"
  setup.kibana.ssl.key: "C:\\Program Files\\Winlogbeat\\winlogbeat.key"
  
  # verification_mode: none
  
  username: "elastic"
  password: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  # Kibana Space ID
  # ID of the Kibana Space into which the dashboards should be loaded. By default,
  # the Default Space will be used.
  #space.id:

# =============================== Elastic Cloud ================================

# These settings simplify using Winlogbeat with the Elastic Cloud (https://cloud.elastic.co/).

# The cloud.id setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.hosts` and
# `setup.kibana.host` options.
# You can find the `cloud.id` in the Elastic Cloud web UI.
#cloud.id:

# The cloud.auth setting overwrites the `output.elasticsearch.username` and
# `output.elasticsearch.password` settings. The format is `<user>:<pass>`.
#cloud.auth:

# ================================== Outputs ===================================

# Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["https://192.168.216.129:9200"]

  # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
  protocol: "https"
  output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authorities: ["C:\\Program Files\\Winlogbeat\\ca.crt"]
  output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: "C:\\Program Files\\Winlogbeat\\winlogbeat.crt"
  output.elasticsearch.ssl.key: "C:\\Program Files\\Winlogbeat\\winlogbeat.key"
  # output.elasticsearch.sslverification_mode: none
  
  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  #api_key: "id:api_key"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

# ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  #hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~

# ================================== Logging ===================================

# Sets log level. The default log level is info.
# Available log levels are: error, warning, info, debug
#logging.level: debug

# At debug level, you can selectively enable logging only for some components.
# To enable all selectors use ["*"]. Examples of other selectors are "beat",
# "publisher", "service".
#logging.selectors: ["*"]

# ============================= X-Pack Monitoring ==============================
# Winlogbeat can export internal metrics to a central Elasticsearch monitoring
# cluster.  This requires xpack monitoring to be enabled in Elasticsearch.  The
# reporting is disabled by default.

# Set to true to enable the monitoring reporter.
#monitoring.enabled: false

# Sets the UUID of the Elasticsearch cluster under which monitoring data for this
# Winlogbeat instance will appear in the Stack Monitoring UI. If output.elasticsearch
# is enabled, the UUID is derived from the Elasticsearch cluster referenced by output.elasticsearch.
#monitoring.cluster_uuid:

# Uncomment to send the metrics to Elasticsearch. Most settings from the
# Elasticsearch output are accepted here as well.
# Note that the settings should point to your Elasticsearch *monitoring* cluster.
# Any setting that is not set is automatically inherited from the Elasticsearch
# output configuration, so if you have the Elasticsearch output configured such
# that it is pointing to your Elasticsearch monitoring cluster, you can simply
# uncomment the following line.
#monitoring.elasticsearch:

# ============================== Instrumentation ===============================

# Instrumentation support for the winlogbeat.
#instrumentation:
    # Set to true to enable instrumentation of winlogbeat.
    #enabled: false

    # Environment in which winlogbeat is running on (eg: staging, production, etc.)
    #environment: ""

    # APM Server hosts to report instrumentation results to.
    #hosts:
    #  - http://localhost:8200

    # API Key for the APM Server(s).
    # If api_key is set then secret_token will be ignored.
    #api_key:

    # Secret token for the APM Server(s).
    #secret_token:


# ================================= Migration ==================================

# This allows to enable 6.7 migration aliases
#migration.6_to_7.enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it took me some time, but I've figured out what was the problem with my certificate.
**I didn't add it to the trusted root store on my windows machine.**

In the end I've created a Winlogbeat crt and key using the elasticsearch-certutil tool by adding a Winlogbeat instance to the instances.yml file and copied the winlogbeat.crt, winlogbeat.key and ca.crt to my windows machine.

Note - You can find all of them under /var/lib/docker/volumes/es_certs/_data/

On the windows machine I configured the Winlogbeat the normal way and in the end I've added the ca.crt to the trusted root store using [this](https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Installation/Add_self_signed_certificate_to_trusted_root_store_on_OutSystems) tutorial.